# Qual é mais aconselhavel a usar, - ou _ para url amigavel

Tags: php

Existe alguma diferença entre utilizar - para _ em urls amigaveis?
ex:

`blog/como-fazer-algo` 
`blog/como_fazer_algo`

Comment: sinceramente não lembro de urls com underscore...

Comment: É muito raro ver URLS com underscore, os browsers conseguem entender mas o internet explorer pode ter alguns problemas na compreensão no uso de `_`.  A google recomenda usar hyphen (-) `blog/como-fazer-algo`, é a pratica mais comum.

Comment: sim, só vejo underscore um parametros.. pode ver mais aqui: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/url-structure

Comment: Olá Jonathan. Boas-vindas ao site. Estou fechando a pergunta pois isso é uma questão de SEO e não sobre programação ([help/on-topic]). Recomendo perguntar (ou buscar) no site: [Webmasters Stack Exchange](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). **Nota:** apesar do que foi dito nas respostas, undescore e hífen não tem haver com questões de complexidade da URL, o uso de um ao invés do outro tem apenas o significado de um representar espaço em motores de busca.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O texto a seguir foi traduzido e adaptado de [Google Central de Pesquisas](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/guidelines/url-structure)

## Mantenha uma estrutura de URL simples.

A estrutura de URL de um site deve ser o mais simples possível. Considere organizar seu conteúdo de forma que os URLs sejam construídos de forma lógica e da maneira mais inteligível para os humanos (quando possível, palavras legíveis em vez de números de ID longos). Por exemplo, se você estiver procurando informações sobre aviação, o seguinte URL pode ajudá-lo a decidir se clica nesse link:

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aviation
```

O seguinte URL é muito menos atraente para os usuários:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?id_sezione=360&sid=3a5ebc944f41daa6f849f730f1
```

Considere o uso de pontuação em seus URLs. O URL `http://www.example.com/green-dress.html` é muito mais útil para nós do que `http://www.example.com/greendress.html`. **Recomendamos que você use hifens(`-`) em vez de sublinhados(`_`) em seus URLs**.

URLs excessivamente complexos, especialmente aqueles que contêm vários parâmetros, podem causar problemas para os rastreadores, criando um número desnecessariamente alto de URLs que apontam para conteúdo idêntico ou semelhante em seu site. Como resultado, o Googlebot pode consumir muito mais largura de banda do que o necessário ou pode não conseguir indexar completamente todo o conteúdo do seu site.